# Test for countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the simplest way to check that a set is countable or not?

With no prior experience on such questions, I want to request an answer to the following question:

Prove that the set $Z^{+} * Z^{+} * Z^{+}$ is countable.

(Pardon the formatting)

Comment: What are those $*$?

Comment: A set is countable if it is in bijection with the set of natural numbers.  That's the simplest, and usually (more or less) only, way.

Comment: Have you seen the proof that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable? It's the same proof that the rationals are countable.

Comment: @user4894, I do not know that proof either. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @vadim123, that definition I know, But how to apply that in this question, is what I do not understand

Comment: @vadim123 I think there are at least two ways to show that a set $S$ is countable which are easier than a bijection; namely, an injection $S\to\mathbb N,$ or a surjection $\mathbb N\to S.$

Comment: @inquisitive Look up the proof that the rationals are countable.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f: \mathbb{Z_+}^3\to \mathbb{N}, f(a,b,c)=2^a3^b5^c$.
From the fundamental theorem of arithmetic it follows that $f$ is 1-1 since if $2^a3^b5^c=2^x3^y5^z \Rightarrow (a,b,c)=(x,y,z).$ This should be enough.